# Customise the Account Linking message in Dialogflow Assistant

Tags: response, dialogflow-es, customization, account-linking

I tried customizing the message that the Assistant says for Account Linking. I am able to add additional messages to it, but unable to change the default message that is fed in the Dialogflow Assistant. 
Is there anyway I can edit the message. If not, can someone help me understand why Google has kept it non-editable?

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible, you can only add an introduction as to why you need the users information.

As for the reason why, it is difficult to say. Ive yet to find anything about it in the documentation, but it could be that Google prefers to have a linking experience that is always the same in every action so that it is recognizable for the user. It also forces you to comply to their standards, such as providing a terms of service on your website as the Google Sign in accountlinking flow mentions.